# FiveThirtyEight: Polls Only vs Now Cast

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, polling

Here is how FiveThirtyEight reports their forecast probabilities.

```
FiveThirtyEight    Clinton    Trump
---------------    -------    -----
Polls Only            51.0     49.0
Now Cast              56.8     43.2
```

What explains the difference between the Polls-Only forecast and the Now-Cast forecast?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. A few days ago, the now-cast had Trump at a 10pt lead, it's since flipped, and now, just 21 hours after your post, it's 63.6/36.4, a large further jump, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers you're comparing are not "poll results", they're odds of winning *based* on the polling.

The details of their models are spelled out [here](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/a-users-guide-to-fivethirtyeights-2016-general-election-forecast/).  They summarize them as:

> **Polls-plus**: Combines polls with an economic index. Since the economic
>   index implies that this election should be a tossup, it assumes the
>   race will tighten somewhat. 
>   **Polls-only**: A simpler,
>   what-you-see-is-what-you-get version of the model. It assumes current
>   polls reflect the best forecast for November, although with a lot of
>   uncertainty. 
>   **Now-cast**: A projection of what would happen in a
>   hypothetical election held today. Much more aggressive than the other
>   models.

Then, they even have a section called "Differences between polls-only and now-cast":

> - The now-cast is basically the polls-only model, except that we lie to
>     our computer and tell it the election is today.
> - As a result, the
>     now-cast is very aggressive. It’s much more confident than polls-plus
>     or polls-only; it weights recent polls more heavily and is more
>     aggressive in calculating a trend line.
> - There could be some big
>     differences around the conventions. The polls-only and polls-plus
>     models discount polls taken just after the conventions, whereas the
>     now-cast will work to quickly capture the convention bounce.